# The plural of "Alter"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I do not know how to differentiate between the "Alter" of some alone and a group of people. What is the plural of "Alter"? Or is using "Alter" as plural customary?

Comment: Alter hat keinen Plural. "Meine Großeltern sind im Alter von 85 bzw. 89 Jahren gestorben." - "Profifußballer sind für gewöhnlich im Alter von 18-35 Jahre." - "Das Alter der Planeten X und Y ist noch nicht bestimmt."

Comment: @Em1: Wieso sollte es für irgendein Wort keinen Plural geben? MIr ist noch kein Fall begegnet, in dem ich keine Verwendung für einen Plural gefunden hätte. Im Laufe des Erwachsenwerdens erlangen Kinder und Jugendliche verschiedene Rechte, die ans Alter geknüpft sind. Kannst Du solche Rechte und die zugehöritgen Alter nennen?

Comment: @userunknown es gibt z.B. nur ein "All", das bringt der Wortstamm irgendwie schon zum Ausdruck.

Comment: @userunknown Ich würde es ja wie folgt sagen: "Kannst du solche Rechte und **das jeweils zugehörige Alter** nennen". Im Bezug auf die Ausgangsfrage, würde ich das Nomen ganz umgehen. "Wie alt sind die 10 Leute". Oder wenn unbedingt mit Nomen "Wie ist das jeweilige Alter der 10 Leute". Aber niemals: "Wie sind die Alter der Leute". Auch wenn es diesen Plural laut Duden sogar gibt, ist das mehr auf grammatischer Ebene. So wie man aus dem Beispiel von vectory auch mehrere "Alle" (ist das richtig?!?) grammatisch erzwingen kann.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

»Alter« as in »what's your age?« is simply never used in plural form in German. [Edit: Okay, looks like some people use the plural form. Still, singular is much, much more common.]

However, the plural form does exist as can be seen by compound forms like »Zeitalter« (historic age) or »Erdzeitalter« (aeons/eons in English/geology):

> Der Geologe kennt alle Erdzeitalter auswendig. *He knows all the eons (their sequence) by heart.*

Deklination:

> **singular:** das Alter, des Alters, dem Alter, das Alter
>
> **plural:** die Alter, der Alter, den Altern, die Alter

Not much of a difference in form, as you can see.

Comment: Of course, the plural of `Alter` exists and is used, albeit seldomly: `Die Alter der Schüler reichen von 9 bis 19.`

Comment: @Toscho: You'd usually say *Das Alter der Schüler reicht von 9 bis 19*. I've never heard *die Alter* myself (which is not to say that it doesn't exist).

Comment: You can say both. In plural, you are referencing the set {Alter des Schülers|Schüler in Klasse}. In singular, you are referencing the mapping Schüler → Alter.

Comment: @Toscho - Kann sein, daß es hier und da benutzt wird. Mir klingt es ungewohnt.

Comment: Die Antwort ist völlig falsch. "Die Alter" ist ein ganz normaler Plural, der überhaupt nicht unüblich ist!

Comment: Das kommt wohl (mal wieder) darauf an, wo man herkommt @äüö. Da wo ich aufgewachsen bin, ist es definitiv unueblich.

Comment: Bsp.: "Die Alter der beiden gesuchten Kinder sind 5 und 7."

Answer (score 4):

According to Wahrig, „Alter“ is uncountable, but Duden gives „die Alter“ as the plural. I agree with Duden, even if the plural is rarely used. The plural certainly is correct for the compound nouns that Ingo mentions.

Answer (score 1):

A common term for age group in German is "Altersklasse", which has the regular plural form "[Altersklassen](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=altersklassen)".

Comment: True, but how does that relate to the question? Carsten, an age grouper ;)

Comment: @Bengt stated that he didn't know 'how to differentiate between the "Alter" of some alone and a group of people'. I believe my answer helps a little there. :)

Answer (score -3):

If you mean:

```
das Alter - (i.e. age)
```

then it really has no plural, though usually composites like "das Zeitalter" or "das Menschenalter" have one.

If you mean the salutation like in:

```
"Eyy, Alter, hast du mal 'n Euro?"
```

then "Alter" is not really a substantive, but an ellipsis of "alter Mann".

There also exist

```
der Alte
die Alte
```

and the plural is

```
die Alten
```

like in "Altenheim" - a home for elder ones.

Comment: If Alter is used as in `Eyy, Alter, hast du mal'n Euro?` then the plural is surely `Alterz`.

Comment: And `Alter` has the plural `Alter`. See comment on Lumi's answer.

Comment: A word of warning for non-native speakers: Never use "Alter" as salutation! Its meaning is just like 'ey, buddy...'

Comment: Wieso sollte Alter keinen Plural haben?

Comment: @userunknown Bin neugierig auf einen Satz mit "Alter" im Plural. Keine Zusammensetzungen wie "Menschenalter", die hatte ich schon abgehandelt.